# Where does GWT Program arguments and VM arguments get saved on HDD?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Where does GWT Program arguments and VM arguments which we configure in Debug/Run configuration(in eclipse) for GWT Application stores on hard drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launch configurations are store in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` directory. Each configuration is saved in a separate `xxx.launch` XML file.

Program arguments are in the entry with key `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS` and VM arguments have the key `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS`